# Regex to match "Item" but not "Items" in JQM Router Plugin

Tags: javascript, regex, jquery-mobile

I am pretty sure this question is all about regex.

I am using the JQM router plugin found [here](https://github.com/azicchetti/jquerymobile-router).  It uses regex to match up pages and bind event handlers. In the docs it states:

> A typical mistake is forgetting the $ operator. If you have two pages,
>   such as #product and #productList, a hypothetical route "#product"
>   would match both pages, leading to unexpected behaviors

Ok.  So I have an #item page and an #items page so I prefixed #item with a $.  But now it doesn't bind the event handler at all.  If i dont use the dollar then the binding for item gets applied to both pages.  This is the actual implementation:

```
var router = new $.mobile.Router([
    {"#items": {events:"i", handler: items.controller.init}},
    {"#items(?:[?/](.*))?": {events:"bs", handler: items.controller.onPageBeforeShow}},

    {"#item": {events:"i", handler: item.controller.init}},
    {"#item(?:[?/](.*))?": {events:"bs", handler: item.controller.onPageBeforeShow}},

]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$` matches the end of the string in regex. You don't want to put it at the beginning, you want it at the end.

For example:

```
#product
  matches
#product
#productList

#product$
  matches
#product
```

Try this code:

```
var router = new $.mobile.Router([
    {"#items$": {events:"i", handler: items.controller.init}},
    {"#items(?:[?/](.*))?$": {events:"bs", handler: items.controller.onPageBeforeShow}},

    {"#item$": {events:"i", handler: item.controller.init}},
    {"#item(?:[?/](.*))?$": {events:"bs", handler: item.controller.onPageBeforeShow}},

]);
```

Comment: I did put it at the end.  But the binding isn't happening

Answer (score 0):

You must postfix, not prefix, *i.e.*

```
#items$
#items(?:[?/](.*))?$
#item$
#item(?:[?/](.*))?$
```

Comment: ahh! I see I was trying to put it after item like so "#item$(?:[?/](.*))?"